# How search an unordered list for a key using reduce?

Tags: python-3.x, reduce

I have a basic reduce function and I want to reduce a list in order to check if an item is in the list. I have defined the function below where f is a comparison function, id_ is the item I am searching for, and a is the list. For example, `reduce(f, 2, [1, 6, 2, 7])` would return True since 2 is in the list.

```
def reduce(f, id_, a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return id_
    elif len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        # can call these in parallel
        res = f(reduce(f, id_, a[:len(a)//2]),
                 reduce(f, id_, a[len(a)//2:]))
        return res
```

I tried passing it a comparison function:

```
def isequal(x, element):
    if x == True:                    # if element has already been found in list -> True
        return True
    if x == element:                 # if key is equal to element -> True
        return True
    else:                            # o.w. -> False
        return False
```

I realize this does not work because x is not the key I am searching for. I get how reduce works with summing and products, but I am failing to see how this function would even know what the key is to check if the next element matches.

I apologize, I am a bit new to this. Thanks in advance for any insight, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, the problem you seem to be trying to solve is determining whether a value is or is not in a list.  In that case `reduce` is probably not the best way to go about that.  To check if a particular value is in a list or not, Python has a much simpler way of doing that:

```
my_list = [1, 6, 2, 7]
print(2 in my_list)
print(55 in my_list)
```

```
True
False
```

Edit: Given OP's comment that they were required to use `reduce` to solve the problem, the code below will work, but I'm not proud of it. ;^)  To see how `reduce` is intended to be used, here is [a good source of information](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/).

Example:

```
from functools import reduce

def test_match(match_params, candidate):
    pattern,  found_match = match_params
    if not found_match and pattern == candidate:
            match_params = (pattern, True)
    return match_params

num_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

_, found_match = reduce(test_match, num_list, (2, False))
print(found_match)

_, found_match = reduce(test_match, num_list, (55, False))
print(found_match)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. I know there are more obvious/efficient ways to do this, but it was an exercise to see if I understood reduce, and I really did not understand how this task could even be done. Safe to say, I did not do so hot...